# Does Volley library handles all the request sequentially

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using `volley` library for performing network operation to speed up the things. My Question is that Does Volley executes the requests which have added in the queue sequentially or parallel.

Suppose I add request like Req1, Req2, Req3 , Will they start to run parallel or second request will wait until first finished ??

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Volley documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

Volley maintains several network threads. If a thread is not doing anything, then it will take on a job in the queue.

To answer your question, Req1, Req2 and Req3 will each be placed in a worker thread and will run in parallel.

Volley also caches your downloaded data (and determines whether to re-download based on the expire time in the HTTP header of the downloaded data), so if your data doesn't need to be downloaded again, it's fetched from the cache, which is faster than re-downloading.

These are some of the reasons that Volley is proclaimed to be faster than standard network operations for the situations that it's appropriate to use it. You can, of course, implement this yourself, but Google has done a lot of the hard work for you.

Comment: Note: They are run in parallel, but not necessarily _all_ of them at once. There is a limit to parallelization, like there is with any network queue, similar to browsers. If you make a hundred requests to a single server, it will wait to start some of them so as not to overload either the device network stack, nor the target server.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a queue starts each operation according to the order it was queued, unless it's a **priority** queue.

Therefore, assuming equal priority (Assuming that the Volley queue is non priority queue), we can conclude that `Req1` will get **started** first. Then `Req2`, followed by `Req3`.

However, we can **not** guarantee the order which each finishes. If `Req1` is time consuming, then the requests will finish in a different order than `Req1`, `Req2`, `Req3`.

All we can guarantee is that they will be started in the order `Req1`, `Req2`, `Req3`.